# How to download Instagram reels, image, dp and stories using python without session?

Tags: python, python-3.x, instagram

I am trying to make instagram content downloader like this [this website](https://reelsdownloader.io/). But the problem is python wants cookies sessions id.

I want to download instagram reels, image, dp, stories, without session id.

Answer (score 1):

I use this code for download reels without session id and instascrape module. Hope you help. +Edit: Unfortunately this code not work for every url:(

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import shutil
import requests



PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=chrome_options)

url = 'https://www.instagram.com/reel/url/'
# Open the YouTube video URL in the browser
driver.get(url)


    

find = driver.find_element(by= By.XPATH, value= '/html/head/script[3]')
text = find.get_attribute('innerText')
driver.close()

start = text.index('"contentUrl":"')
end = text.index('","thumbnailUrl"',start+14)
print(text)
new_text = text[start+14:end].replace('\/','/')

print('--------------')
print(new_text)
response = requests.get(new_text,stream=True)
with open ('output.mp4','wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw,out_file)
del response
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not related to Python generally.
If you want to scrape data from Instagram you have to pass session keys and simulate real client connection (try https://github.com/chris-greening/instascrape or similar libraries).

Or you can use official Instagram Graph API (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/) which is better option if those rights scope meets your requirements.